# Mongodb python/disnake/discord.py почему ошибка вызывается?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Итаааак! Я покажу вам код, скрины и т.д

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
import os
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '>', help_command = None, intents = disnake.Intents.all(), activity = disnake.Game('>help | /help', status = disnake.Status.dnd))

cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://Skyship:Nika2123@cluster0.apm0p8v.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
collection = cluster.cluster0.colldb

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"your {client.user} client online.")

for guild in client.guilds:
    for member in guild.members:
        post = {
            "id": member.id,
            "balance": 0,
            "bank": 0,
        }
        if collection.count_documents({
            "id": member.id }) == 0:
                collection.insert_one(post)
    
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    post = {
        "id": 0,
        "balance": 0,
        "bank": 0
    }
    if collection.count_documents({
        "id": member.id }) == 0:
            collection.insert_documents(post)

for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

client.run("")
```

Скриншоты:

[image: ошибка монгодб]

[image: ошибка монгодб]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так предполагаю, что программа запускается на чём-то линуксоподобном.

Судя по ошибке, программа пытается разрешить какое-то DNS-имя - и не может это сделать, поскольку не может найти в системе файл конфигурации DNS (`/etc/resolv.conf`).

Так что я бы начал с проверки того, настроен ли на системе DNS (подозреваю, что он не настроен). Ещё можно попробовать создать файл `/etc/resolv.conf` со списком DNS-серверов в нём - возможно, это починит проблему хотя бы до перезагрузки. Почитать об этом файле можно [тут](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/tcp_conf/tcp07.html) или [там](https://itisgood.ru/2021/06/03/kak-sdelat-postojannymi-izmenenija-dns-v-resolv-conf-na-linux/).

Comment: Спасибо большое за данный ответ:)

Comment: Это помогло решение моей проблемы.